# Stacks and Queues are linear data structure or non linear data structure?

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

I have been facing this problem since long time. Few authors say that stacks and queues are linear data structure and in few non-linear. Which one is right and why?

In wikipedia, it is given that queue is a linear data structure. I too believe that they are linear, as there are no diversions as in the case of trees. However, while attempting an online test, it was overridden saying that these are non-linear.

Please answer me in precise, which is true and why.

Comment: Ok, now can you clarify what you mean by a linear data-structure? And which online-test did you do?

Comment: Depends what kind of queue. A FIFO queue is linear, a priority queue isn't (at least, not if it's implemented so as to keep the basic operations fast). But then, a FIFO queue and a stack *could* both be implemented using a priority queue, if you wanted to.

Comment: There are at least two C++ concepts that could be considered "linear", the "contiguous" concept and the "Sequence" concept. They lead to radically different answers.

Comment: @MSalters: the C++ standard has complexity requirements for some functions. That's the first thing that came to my mind when I saw the title.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by "linear" here? They're certainly neither circular nor spherical.

Also, the answer will depend on what stacks/queues you're talking about.

---

Did you mean "contiguous"?

If you mean `std::stack` and `std::queue` (then remove the "C" tag from your question, please), then it still depends. They're both *container adaptors* meaning that the underlying implementation can be specified as a template parameter. By default, `std::stack` and `std::queue` are built on `std::deque` — which **is not** guaranteed to be contiguous.

For some other arbitrary container specification, it would depend.

---

Did you mean "sequence"?

Standard C++ [has three sequence containers](http://www.deitel.com/articles/cplusplus_tutorials/20060120/Cplusplus_Tutorial1_IntrotoSequenceContainers/index.html): `std::vector`, `std::list` and `std::deque`. This means that a `std::stack`/`std::queue` is not a sequence container in itself, but its implementation *may* be, depending on which one you pick.

---

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It depends! A queue/stack can be linear as in the case of FIFO and LIFO, however it can be non-linear in the case of priority queue for example, where serving an element depends on some parameter you specify!
So, both can be true! It all depends on how you implement the data-structure you are using!
However, most likely a stack is considered linear, a queue can be both, linked lists and trees are non-linear.

Answer (score 0):

For me, a queue or a stack is only a specification. The implementation can vary.

Answer (score 0):

Either can be true. The words "stack" and "queue" only define the permitted access patterns, not the implementation details. For example, you can implement either as a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

liner datastructure has nothing to to with it's implementation detail or its memory model. It just means all its elements has its preceding or following, exclude the head and end. Not like a tree or gragh.

Liner datastructure includes queue, stack.

If somebody mis uses the liner as "Continouse memory", he/she is wrong.